# Scroll to bottom of hidden div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple chat JS application, with a `div.chat-holder` holding all chat messages within a pane on the overall window. I set height of '`.chat-holder` so it remains fixed in size, and allows for scrolling of all the messages.

```
<style>
 .chat-holder {
     height: 30px;
     overflow-y: scroll;
 }
</style>
<div class="pane">
    <div class="chat-holder">
      <div class="chat-item">
         first msg
      </div>
      <div class="chat-item">
         second msg
      </div>
      ....
      <div class="chat-item">
         last msg
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

On page load, I scroll to the bottom by setting the scrollTop of the holder:

```
var $holder = $('.chat-holder');
$holder.scrollTop($holder[0].scrollHeight);
```

and this works fine.

Problem occurs when I start with `div.pane` set to `display:none`. Ideally, I look to have a separate event to "show/hide" the chat pane, and start with the pane hidden.

When the parent pane is hidden, the `.chat-holder` scrollHeight is 0, so **on load**, the hidden pane won't be scrolled to the bottom. Which means when the pane is displayed, the chats are not scrolled to the most recent chats. You can see this in the following snippet: with `.pane` initially not displayed, scroll isn't set. If you set `.pane` to start displayed, then scroll works fine.

Is there anyway to "scroll to the bottom" while parent is hidden? (Yes, I know I could do this by detecting when the chat-holder is exposed & then scroll to the bottom, but I'm looking to do it on load.)

```js
$(function() {
   var $holder = $('.chat-holder');
   $holder.scrollTop($holder[0].scrollHeight);
   
   $('button').click(function() {
        $('.pane').toggleClass('active');
   });
});
```

```css
.chat-holder {
   height: 30px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   border: thin solid black;
 }
 .chat-item {
   font-size: 20px;
 }
 
 .pane {
    display: none;
 }
 .pane.active {
    display: block;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pane">
   <div class="chat-holder">
      <div class="chat-item">first msg</div>
      <div class="chat-item">second msg</div>
      <div class="chat-item">last msg</div>
   </div>
</div>

<button>Toggle pane</button>
```

Comment: The display: none is the issue because that will make the element "removed" from the DOM, so when you reference it, it's like it doesn't exist. I would suggest using height: 0; overflow: hidden; or opacity: 0; if you are trying to get its position. If you needed to keep the display: none, you could apply that styling after the page loads via javascript. So you would get the position on load, then apply display: none.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get creative and use `opacity` or `visibility` rules instead of `display: none`:

```js
$(function() {
   var $holder = $('.chat-holder');
   $holder.scrollTop($holder[0].scrollHeight);
   
   $('button').click(function() {
        $('.pane').toggleClass('active');
   });
});
```

```css
.chat-holder {
   height: 30px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   border: thin solid black;
 }
 .chat-item {
   font-size: 20px;
 }
 
 .pane {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
 }
 .pane.active {
    opacity: 1;
    position: relative;
 }
 button {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pane">
   <div class="chat-holder">
      <div class="chat-item">first msg</div>
      <div class="chat-item">second msg</div>
      <div class="chat-item">last msg</div>
   </div>
</div>

<button>Toggle pane</button>
```

Comment: Works as desired. Thank you!

Comment: One improvement is to add CSS `visibility` with opacity in `div.pane`. By having the pane initially invisible (visibility:hidden) it still calculates the scroll properly, but -- being invisible -- doesn't confuse accessibility readers (and alt-tab) which can "see" transparent fields, but cannot "see" invisible fields.